# ImageView on Toolbar pushed by menu icon

Tags: android, menu, icons, toolbar

Image

[Screen Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9TG5.png)

I have an `ImageView` inside a `Toolbar`, and now I added a `menu` with an `icon` inside. How can I do to keep my `ImageView` centred and not being pushed by this `icon`? Watch the screen capture on top.

This is my ImageView xml

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imagePowerlist"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/powerlist"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

Comment: try changing the `android:paddingLeft="10dp"` to `android:paddingLeft="34dp"`

Comment: The problem with that is that I have another fragment with the same ImageView but without the menu, so changing padding is not an option @Shinilms

Comment: then change the padding of the imageview dynamically